# Is there any way to check the value of aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a policy that denies operations except if [aws global context key `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html) is true. Meaning that the operation requires that you are authenticated via MFA.

The policy is working ok, and I can see that when I use my aws profile without mfa the operations are denied and when I use the profile with MFA they work.

Now, **is there any command / api operation that tells me if my credentials used MFA (`aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent`)?**

I need it for troubleshooting purpose mainly when other people complain that they are getting Operation Denied? Something like `aws sts get-caller-identity` but that also print out if the credentials used an MFA code.

Comment: Not personally aware of any indicator in the returned STS credentials or in the subsequent denied API response. If you have full control over the process by which credentials are vended, maybe you could persist a list of access keys that were generated by a GetSessionToken request that included MFA serial? Sounds painful though.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would want to check if certain users did authenticate themselves with MFA before doing some operations in your account.

I'm not aware of any kind of CLI command for this. What would be helpful for you is to take a look a the [CloudTrail Event History](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events.html). This should log all the operations done by other users. If you download this list of events as a JSON, you should be able find a section with `sessionContext` for every event.

```
"sessionContext": {
    "sessionIssuer": {
        "type": "Role",
        "principalId": "...",
        "arn": "...",
        "accountId": "...",
        "userName": "..."
    },
    "webIdFederationData": {},
    "attributes": {
        "creationDate": "2022-02-18T14:08:57Z",
        "mfaAuthenticated": "false"
    }
}
```

We can notice that every it is logged that session used by the user/role is MFA authenticated or not.

If you are willing to search for operations done by certain users, you should be able to detect if they were using MFA or not. Just as warning, this JSON file can be huge and could be really painful to go through it.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to make sure that users are using MFA when working with AWS CLI you can also enforce MFA usage with `aws sts get-session-token` (see also https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/get-session-token.html). Therefore users start creating a temporary session with explicit MFA usage (see parameter `--serial-numer` and `--token-code`). All commands execute with these temporary session credentials are MFA enforced.